# How many bytes of bytecode has a particular method in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I recently read on [Jon Masamitsu's Weblog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/did_you_know) that huge methods (8000 bytes of bytecode) are not JIT compiled with HotSpot.

So my question is: how do I find out (as a programmer) how many bytes of bytecode a particular method has?

The JIT compiler of course seems to know. Can I extract this piece of information from the `.class` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `javap -c mypackage.MyClass` to dump the bytecode of your class (and see the size of each method)

Generally speaking, you should know that a method is too large to read and understand before you hit this limit.  IMHO its more a problem for generated code. BTW There is a hard limit of 65536 bytes in a method.

Comment: Yep, an 8k+ byte method should be several hundred lines of code large which seems exceedingly unlikely in non-generated code.

Comment: I can decompile it that way, but could you please elaborate how to "see the size of each method"?

Comment: When you decompile a method it shows you the offset of each instruction. Look at the offset of the last instruction.

Comment: This means if e.g. "424: areturn" is the last instruction, 424 is the total number of bytecodes?

Comment: Close. The length of `areturn` is 1, so add one.

Comment: @Voo It's easy to accidently generate huge methods from small amounts of source code by abusing array initializers. There's one method in the JRE that's over 28kb because of overuse of array initializers. Finally blocks are even bigger potential source of code bloat, but they're rarely used.

Comment: If you want to see private methods as well, add ```-private```