# Determining Java Method Size from Within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode

What is the easiest way to determine the size of a Java method (measured in bytecodes) from within Eclipse?

Here is one way of doing this outside of Eclipse: [How many bytes of bytecode has a particular method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345034/how-many-bytes-of-bytecode-has-a-particular-method-in-java), but it would be ideal to have some way of seeing this from within the IDE.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a plugin, or how to do it yourself?

Comment: Compile and disassemble it. There's not really any other way to tell for sure.

Comment: What I am asking is is there a plugin (or maybe Eclipse has this natively) for "Compile and disassemble" the method. It would be ideal if there were an easy way of selecting the method from the explorer. For example, [Metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) calculates lines of code per method.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) provides few levels of granulity for displaying coverage - lines, branches, cyclomatic complexity and **instructions**, among others. It's not a dedicated solution, but it seems to work pretty well. In addition, it's a really neat code coverage plugin.

Comment: Is bytecode size one of the measures? Or only instruction count? They are not quite the same.

Comment: As far as I know, only the instruction count. I wasn't sure what did you mean by "bytecodes", I suppose number of bytecode instructions is a valid interpretation.

Comment: In this case I am concerned with the actual method size measured in byte codes. Because instructions differ in the number of byte codes they take up this is not the same measure as number of instructions. The method size matters for various jvm optimizations.